# Move one arraylist data to another arraylist in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

How to move one Arraylist data  to another arraylist. I have tried for many option but the output is in the form of array not arraylist

Comment: Are you wanting a deep or shallow copy of the elements?

Answer (score 16):

First - unless you are on .NET 1.1, you should a avoid `ArrayList` - prefer typed collections such as `List<T>`.

When you say "copy" - do you want to *replace*, *append*, or *create new*?

For append (using `List<T>`):

```
    List<int> foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    List<int> bar = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    foo.AddRange(bar);
```

To replace, add a `foo.Clear();` before the `AddRange`. Of course, if you know the second list is long enough, you could loop on the indexer:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < bar.Count ; i++) {
        foo[i] = bar[i];
    }
```

To create new:

```
    List<int> bar = new List<int>(foo);
```

Comment: why did you recommend using List<T> instead of ArrayList unless using .NET 1.1???

Comment: @kashif type safety (avoiding stupid bugs), performance (boxing and memory), better API, support for LINQ, etc... Why *wouldn't* someone prefer the generic version? The only edge case I know about here is Hashtable, which still retains some usage because it has a much better threading model than Dictionary`2

Answer (score 6):

```
        ArrayList model = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList copy = new ArrayList(model);
```

?

Answer (score 6):

Use the constructor of the ArrayList that takes an ICollection as a parameter.
Most of the collections have this constructor.

```
ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(oldList);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ArrayList l1=new ArrayList();
l1.Add("1");
l1.Add("2");
ArrayList l2=new ArrayList(l1);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange.aspx

shameless copy/paste from the above link

```
  // Creates and initializes a new ArrayList.
  ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
  myAL.Add( "The" );
  myAL.Add( "quick" );
  myAL.Add( "brown" );
  myAL.Add( "fox" );

  // Creates and initializes a new Queue.
  Queue myQueue = new Queue();
  myQueue.Enqueue( "jumped" );
  myQueue.Enqueue( "over" );
  myQueue.Enqueue( "the" );
  myQueue.Enqueue( "lazy" );
  myQueue.Enqueue( "dog" );

  // Displays the ArrayList and the Queue.
  Console.WriteLine( "The ArrayList initially contains the following:" );
  PrintValues( myAL, '\t' );
  Console.WriteLine( "The Queue initially contains the following:" );
  PrintValues( myQueue, '\t' );

  // Copies the Queue elements to the end of the ArrayList.
  myAL.AddRange( myQueue );

  // Displays the ArrayList.
  Console.WriteLine( "The ArrayList now contains the following:" );
  PrintValues( myAL, '\t' );
```

Other than that I think [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527561/move-one-arraylist-data-to-another-arraylist-in-c/527577#527577) is spot on ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for moving up the data like :

```
Firstarray.AddRange(SecondArrary);
```